# Can REPLACE() be made accent insensitive (é = e)?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

I have a table which uses `UTF-8- default` collation.

I have a column in this table called `company` which has this value `Café Rouge`

When I do the query like:

```
 select * from company where name ='Cafe Rouge'
```

it lists this company because it treats the character `é =e` but when I use the replace command, it does not treat  `é` as `e`.

So,

```
select replace('Café Rouge','e','z')
```

gives me `'Café Rougz'` i.e. it does not replace `é` with `z`.

Any suggestions will be appreciable

Comment: I'm not sure whether this behaviour can be changed - `REPLACE()` is probably doing a binary comparison. Is it not an option to simply speficially replace `é`?

Comment: why you need to replace 'é'? you should probably create new column `company_normalized` where you put value without accent, trimed, with normalized spaces etc. and then you simple use normalized variant where it is helpfull, and real company name otherwise...

Comment: No :( it isnt an option because there may be many more such characters which will cause problem.Also I cannot change my table to binary collation because we are currently using case insensitivity everywhere and changing it to binary will mean changes at various places.

Comment: [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-result.html) says that `REPLACE()` is supposed to work that way, so you'll have to roll your own function. `Note: The REPLACE() function, unlike all other functions, always ignores the collation of the string input and performs a case-sensitive comparison.`

Comment: I second @Pekka웃. First replace all accented characters with their accentless version like `create view accentless_e_view as select replace(name, 'é', 'e') from company; create view accentless_a_view as select replace(name, 'á', 'a') from company;` and so on.

Comment: @DrH If at all, it would be `select replace(replace(name, 'è', 'e'), 'à', 'a') from company;`

Comment: Thank you, @fancyPants, I forgot `replace` calls can be cascaded into each other :)

Answer (score 1):

I think among the good things you can do is maintain a second column which keeps these strings in a normal form; for example, this column would hold "Cafe Rouge" rather than "Café Rouge". You can project the exceptional characters in your query and then use the normal form column to query against.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(name USING ascii), 'e', 'z')
```

to convert the `name` column to ASCII before doing the replace.

Comment: I thought of this too, but it will destroy data and is hence likely to be useless. Imagine `Café Üntenbärger` -> it would end up `Cafz Untenbarger`

Comment: But if you want to use a different version of the 'name' data for comparison, you could load the replaced version with an alias so that the original 'name' would also be available.

It would be helpful if you explain your intention more clearly.

Comment: I get your point, but how would you do the comparison in mySQL? I don't think it's possible. (You'd need a scripting language to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this outside of mySQL.

You can normalize the string inside mySQL as shown by @Christian using `CONVERT()`, but that will destroy any other non-ASCII characters present:

```
Bürgercafé Römer
```

would end up

```
Burgercafz Romer
```

characters from other character sets like Cyrillic or Chinese would be erased altogether.

Your best best is to either specifically replace all the characters you want to replace.

```
replace('Café Rouge','e','z')  
replace('Café Rouge','é','z')  
replace('Café Rouge','è','z')
```

To do *exactly* what you want, you'd have to load every string into a programming language like PHP.

There, you could do the following:

1. Load the string from the database; make sure it's UTF-8
2. Split the string into its characters (be aware of multibyte characters - use [`mb_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php))
3. Walk through each character
4. Normalize the character using `iconv($character, "UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT");`
5. If the normalized character results in `e`, you know you'll need to replace it in your string.
6. Write the altered string back into the database.

This, however, looks like an awful lot of trouble for what seems like a small thing. Are you really sure it's necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. A safer bet would be to simply do a replace on those particular characters.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you perform a selection on café rouge, and replace the desired column on each of the returned results?